# How avoid repetition using apply function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame named `new_data` having two lists of columns :

```
l = ["l_1stIn","l_1stWon", "l_2ndWon","l_ace", "l_bpFaced","l_df","l_age","l_rank_gap","l_rank_points","l_1stIn"]

w = ["w_1stIn","w_1stWon", "w_2ndWon","w_ace", "w_bpFaced","w_df", "w_age","w_rank_gap","w_rank_points","w_1stIn"]
```

I want to create new data frame having new columns which are the result of the difference between
the two lists of columns mentioned below :

```
loss['1stIn'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_1stIn, x.w_1stIn), axis=1)
loss['1stWon'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_1stWon, x.w_1stWon), axis=1)
loss['2ndWon'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_2ndWon, x.w_2ndWon), axis=1)
loss['ace'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_ace, x.w_ace), axis=1)
loss['bpFaced'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_bpFaced, x.w_bpFaced), axis=1)
loss['df'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_df, x.w_df), axis=1)
loss['age'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_age, x.w_age), axis=1)
loss['ht'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_ht, x.w_ht), axis=1)
loss['rank_gap'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_rank_gap, x.w_rank_gap), axis=1)
loss['rank_points'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_rank_points, x.w_rank_points), axis=1)
loss['1stIn'] = new_data.apply(lambda x: f(x.l_1stIn, x.w_1stIn), axis=1)
```

So, I want to create new dataframe `loss` as given below but without repeating many times apply function. I am looking for general function which have as input the three list :

```
l = ["l_1stIn","l_1stWon", "l_2ndWon","l_ace", "l_bpFaced","l_df","l_age","l_rank_gap","l_rank_points","l_1stIn"]

w = ["w_1stIn","w_1stWon", "w_2ndWon","w_ace", "w_bpFaced","w_df","w_age","w_rank_gap","w_rank_points","w_1stIn"]

output = ["1stIn","1stWon", "2ndWon","ace",
 "bpFaced","df","age", "rank_gap","rank_points","1stIn"]
```

and return the final data frame `loss` having `output` as columns which is the result of difference between `l` and `w`

Comment: It's not that complicated to write such a function. You know that you can access columns of a dataframe using the index notation: when you do `col = "l_1stIn"`, `df[col]` gives you that column of the dataframe. Now apply that idea to each new column that you want. Once you've made an attempt, ask a _specific_ question about your code.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, I am beginner in python, and I am looking for optimization solution to avoid each time the repetition. I will see how can do that using index as you proposed. Thank you any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function to take a pair of columns and return a column output like so:

```
def do_calculation(col0, col1):
    # Do something with both columns and then return the result
    # For example,
    return col0 - col1
```

Next, let's write a function to take a *bunch* of input and output columns, and invoke `doCalculation()` with the correct inputs.

```
def process_data(func, data, inputs_0, inputs_1, outputs):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    # zip to iterate over all three lists together
    for col_in0, col_in1, col_out in zip(inputs_0, inputs_1, outputs):
        in0 = data[col_in0] # Get the first input col
        in1 = data[col_in1] # Second input col
        df[col_out] = func(in0, in1) # Call the given func and set its output as the output column

    return df
```

And finally, let's create a dummy dataframe and call this function:
In my dataframe, each row describes a bank account and contains four columns: The previous balance , an amount to debit, the holder's age now, and the holder's age when they opened the account. We're going to calculate the current balance, and the number of years they have held the account.

```
import io
csvtext="""old_balance,debit_amount,age_current,age_start
100,20,50,45
500,10,30,10
200,100,80,30"""
in_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csvtext)) # Read the dataframe
```

```
   old_balance  debit_amount  age_current  age_start
0          100            20           50         45
1          500            10           30         10
2          200           100           80         30
```

If you were doing it using your method, you'd do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['new_balance'] = in_df.apply(lambda x: x.old_balance - x.debit_amount, axis=1)
df['customer_for'] = in_df.apply(lambda x: x.age_current - x.age_start, axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
   new_balance  customer_for
0           80             5
1          490            20
2          100            50
```

To call our function, we need to give it the function that does the calculations, the input data, the input columns

```
inputs_0 = ["old_balance", "age_current"]
inputs_1 = ["debit_amount", "age_start"]
outputs = ["new_balance", "customer_for"]

df = process_data(do_calculation, in_df, inputs_0, inputs_1, outputs)
```

The result of this is the same as the previous code, without all that repetition.

Comment: thank you for this solution, but I got this error : `NameError: name 'col_in0' is not defined`

Comment: @Rprogrammer Oops, typo. Change the line to `for col_in0, col_in1, col_out in zip(inputs_0, inputs_1, outputs):`

Comment: I tried `for col_in0, col_in1, col_out in zip(inputs_0, inputs_1, outputs):`, but no way

Comment: What do you mean? I've updated the code in my answer to fix that typo.